# Downloading images directly from Parse.com, as opposed to using their API

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I noticed that for a PFFile type Object stored on my Parse.com developer account, the link is open and accessible for anyone to view/download.

Example a PFFile Object that is named, name.jpg, representing an image could be a URL like :

```
http://files.parsetfss.com/<some garbled class UUID>/<some garbled image uuid>-name.jpg

Where <some garbled class UUID> appears to be the same for all name.jpg, stored on a class

and <some garbled image uuid>-name.jpg appears to be unique uuid's appended with the actual object name which is 'name.jpg'
```

Using the above URL, anyone/any client can download the object

So I have some questions regarding this:

1. Is this normal? Is this by design?
2. Will the URL for an object change, if nothing else changes?
3. Am I being unwise in using this information to download images directly, thereby saving the cost of one API call from Parse (although I think I'll make one API call anyways to get the URL) ?
4. Will downloading directly from this URL, perform better/acceptable compared to downloading via Parse.com API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's normal. Protection is via the object, don't give access to anyone who shouldn't have it.

No the URL shouldn't change, though strictly you should query from the file object each time you want it to be sure.

You should care more about network calls that API calls in general. You could use cloud code to aggregate responses, or batch requests, but that doesn't reduce API calls.

The download is unchanged as you're always downloading the same file from the same link no matter which API you use to do it.

Comment: Thanks! You make some great points. The actual use case is one of a client needing to download multiple images from a parse.com repository and view it on an App. With some googling i also found this http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/loading-remote-images-stored-on-parse/ so Im thinking given the object IDs i should be able to execute a download using PFImageView